# How to create a button to select all checkbuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

I want to create a list of checkboxes in Python with TkInter and try to select all checkboxes with a button.

Help me find a solution to my problem, I've wasted a lot of time on it.

```
from tkinter import *


def on_click():
    lst = [interests[i] for i, chk in enumerate(chks) if chk.get()]
    print(",".join(lst))


interests = ['Music', 'Book', 'Movie', 'Photography', 'Game', 'Travel']
root = Tk()
root.option_add("*Font", "impact 30")
chks = [BooleanVar() for i in interests]

Label(root, text="Your interests", bg="gold").pack()
for i, s in enumerate(interests):
    Checkbutton(root, text=s, variable=chks[i]).pack(anchor=W)  # W = West

Button(root, text="submit", command=on_click).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want the Submit button the check them all or are you asking for another button to be created that checks all buttons. You could add a button with a command that loops though all check buttons BooleanVars (```chks``` list) and set their values. It would actually be quite similar to your current ```on_click``` command except you would ```set``` the values instead of ```get```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new button called "select all" with the following line.

```
Button(root, text="select all", command=select_all).pack()
```

Which I connected to the `select_all` function here.

```
def select_all(): 
    for c in chks: c.set(True)
```

This function sets all checkboxes to `True`.

Which leads to ...

```
from tkinter import *


def on_click():
    lst = [interests[i] for i, chk in enumerate(chks) if chk.get()]
    print(",".join(lst))

def select_all():
    for c in chks: c.set(True)

interests = ['Music', 'Book', 'Movie', 'Photography', 'Game', 'Travel']
root = Tk()
root.option_add("*Font", "impact 30")
chks = [BooleanVar() for i in interests]

Label(root, text="Your interests", bg="gold").pack()
for i, s in enumerate(interests):
    Checkbutton(root, text=s, variable=chks[i]).pack(anchor=W)  # W = West

Button(root, text="select all", command=select_all).pack()
Button(root, text="submit", command=on_click).pack()
root.mainloop()
```